# Create block programmatically based on node content

Tags: views, blocks

In Views we can create a block that the content depends on the content of a node using contextual filters. So we can pass variables and check the visibility of the Views-Block.

Let’s say in our content type we have a field that has a text-field. In Views->Contextual->Our field->Provide default value-> content ID from URL can grab this.

But creating a block programmatically

```
hook_block_view($delta = '') {
…
$block['content'] = theme('item_list', array(
         'items' => ???,
          'type' => 'ul',
        ));
…
}
```

How we can grab these values form the node-field?

And if there are no values how we will hide the block?

Comment: So do you want the contextual nid and relevant field of that node in block ?

Comment: Short answer: yes. I don't use views at all (in this implementation), so I want a (proper) way to grab the content of the node field from a certain content type in a block (while the node is rendered normally in the main content), and check if exist. Because the block will be assigned in a region but the field (I want to display) is only in one content-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `menu_get_object()` to get the current node. Refer [`menu_get_object`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

> `menu_get_object()` provides access to objects loaded by the current router item. For example, on the page node/%node, the router loads the %node object, and calling `menu_get_object()` will return that.

If you want to hide the block (not only the content) warp the `return $block;` in `if`.

```
if (isset(menu_get_object()->some_field) {
  ...
  return block;
}
```

Comment: It's exactly that I need! So simple but I was so far away! Many thanks!

Comment: Add/edit my solution

Comment: The [hook_block_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) says if you return an empty block array then the block won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a few modules depending on your need:

[Node field block](https://drupal.org/project/node_fields_block)

> An easy way to create blocks with a collection of node fields. Focused on letting customers manage most of the content on a page in just one node. You can create multiple blocks for a node with one or a combination of fields and move them in different regions.

[Field as block](https://drupal.org/project/fieldblock)

> Field as Block provides an easy way to display one or more fields of the current node in a block.

There's a custom way also if you want. You can use below function for this purpose.

```
render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_myfield'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but as I say I need it to do programmatically. The problem behind it's much more complicated.. And because it's complicated I can't use the render.